# We are everywhere

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

Each of the small images corresponds to at most 5 letters. The answer to this puzzle is a word.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> [image: ELEMENTS]

Each rebus-type image

> yields a word. Subtracting the letters indicated above yields one or two letters. Each is an element symbol.

The image at the very top

> hints that we should draw lines connecting the elements in the table.

Each line of images

> forms one letter. Pluses indicate lifting the pen.

Full explanation of images

> ```
>  CAR      -3          Ca  Calcium
>  OK       -1          K   Potassium
>  RIB      -2          Rb  Rubidium
>  COS      -2          Cs  Caesium
>  AFRO     -1,-4       Fr  Francium
>  RA                   Ra  Radium
>  +
>  RIB      -2          Rb  Rubidium
>  SIR      -2          Sr  Strontium
>
>
>  SOCK     -2,-4       Sc  Scandium
>  YES      -2,-3       Y   Yttrium
>  LUCK     -3,-4       Lu  Lutetium    (thanks to Synchronous)
>  LAR      -2          Lr  Lawrencium  (thanks to Synchronous)
>  ROOF     -2,-3       Rf  Rutherfordium
>
>
>  CAR      -2          Cr  Chromium
>  TV       -1          V   Vanadium
>  NIB      -2          Nb  Niobium
>  TAZ      -3          Ta  Tantalum
>  DAB      -2          Db  Dubnium
>  STIG     -2,-3       SG  Seaborgium  (thanks to Synchronous)
>  +
>  NIB      -2          Nb  Niobium
>  MOON     -3,-4       Mo  Molybdenum
>
>
>  BOHR     -2,-4       Bh  Bohrium
>  REM      -3          Re  Rhenium
>  TACO     -2,-4       Tc  Technetium
>  MOON     -2,-3       Mn  Manganese
>  COS      -1          Os  Osmium
>  COS      -3          Co  Cobalt
>  RHINO    -3,-4,-5    Rh  Rhodium
>  MIR      -1          Ir  Iridium
>  MEAT     -2,-3       Mt  Meitnerium
>
>
>  CUP      -3          Cu  Copper
>  NICK     -3,-4       Ni  Nickel
>  IPAD     -1,-3       Pd  Palladium
>  POT      -2          Pt  Platinum
>  DOS      -2          Ds  Darmstadtium
>  RUG      -2          Rg  Roentgenium
>  +
>  IPAD     -1,-3       Pd  Palladium
>  AGE      -3          Ag  Silver
>
>
>  CAN      -2          Cn  Copernicium
>  HOG      -2          Hg  Mercury
>  CD                   Cd  Cadmium
>  ZONE     -2,-4       Zn  Zinc
>  NHL      -3          Nh  Nihonium
>  TAIL     -2,-3       Tl  Thallium
>  IN                   In  Indium
>  GAS      -3          Ga  Gallium
>
>
>  AGE      -1          Ge  Germanium
>  GAS      -1          As  Arsenic
>  SET      -3          Se  Selenium
>  +
>  GAS      -1          As  Arsenic
>  SAAB     -2,-3       Sb  Antimony
>  BIN      -3          Bi  Bismuth
>  MIC      -2          Mc  Moscovium
>
>
>  KARAT    -2,-4,-5    Kr  Krypton
>  BOHR     -2,-3       Br  Bromine
>  IT       -2          I   Iodine
>  AXE      -1          Xe  Xenon
>  RON      -2          Rn  Radon
>  HOG      -1          Og  Oganesson
>  ANTS     -1,-2       Ts  Tennessine
> ```

Comment: Nice job! I didn't get past deciphering the images, but I can fill in your missing words: ROT13(BC hfrf gur ynfg ryrzragf bs gur ynagunavqrf naq npgvavqrf, abg gur svefg barf. Guvf zrnaf TBBQ YHPX -> Yh naq YNE -> Ye. Naq lbhe F__T vf FGVT.)

Comment: Well done!  Everything looks good, but as @Synchronous points out rot13 (V hfrq gur ynfg ryrzragf bs obgu tebhcf (Yh naq Ye). Sbe fbzr ernfba gur crevbqvp gnoyr V hfrq, hfrq gubfr vafgrnq. Fb n fznyy reebe gurer sebz zl fvqr. Nyfb, Gur "Fgvt" vf pbeerpg sbe Ft.)

Comment: @Synchronous good catch! I'll edit it in.